# Is Apple Cinnamon Oats an Indian recipe?

Tags: oats, cinnamon, apple

Is Apple Cinnamon Oats an Indian recipe? If not then are there any variations how it is prepared elsewhere in the world?

Comment: Can you provide an example as to how that dish is prepared in Indian Cuisine?  Apple Cinnamon Oatmeal is very popular in the U.S., but it might be a completely different dish than what you're speaking of.

Comment: Do you mean Native American or Indian? None of those ingredients sound particularly unique to the Indian subcontinent, I'd associate that more with Scotland than anything else. Unless you mean something other than the breakfast cereal dish?

Comment: @Jacob G Sure! Here is the link. FYI: http://simpleindianrecipes.com/applecinnamonoats.aspx . And yes, there are so many other recipes there that may have variations in North america as well.

Comment: @Yamikuronue When i say "Indian", i mean the Indian Subcontinent. Soctland does have a lot of oat recipes. Please view this link here: http://www.simpleindianrecipes.com/applecinnamonoats.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the recipe, it appears to be just a basic porridge. So no, I wouldn't say that's unique to Indian Cuisine; [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porridge) suggests it's "traditional and common in English-speaking countries, Nordic countries, and Germany". This is specifically rolled-oat porridge:

> "Rolled oat porridge is common in England, Australia, New Zealand, North America and Scandinavia. It is known as simply "porridge" or, more commonly in the United States and often in Canada, "oatmeal"."

Wiki suggests wheat, maize, and rice porridge are more traditional in India, so I suspect this is a modern adaptation owing to the ubiquity of rolled oats in supermarkets.

Answer (score 3):

Oats is very new to India. I am an Indian and I think oats came to Indian market only 5-6 years earlier. Even now oats is considered food for people who are on diet and still not eaten regularly.Most of my friends do not like the taste and texture of oats. People now have started making Dosas and idlis (traditional Indian breakfast) out of it, replacing rice with oats.

Answer (score -2):

[Apples and Cinnamon](http://www.quakeroats.com/products/oatmeal/instant-oatmeal/apples-with-cinnamon.aspx) is arguably one of the tastiest flavors of instant oatmeal in the US. It fills the bellies of countless American kids before school, and surely some of their parents too. Oatmeal is regarded as everyday (American) food, definitely not associated with Indian cuisine, with or without apples and cinnamon.

Comment: What does this have to do with India? It being popular in the US doesn't mean that it can't also be common in India.

Comment: @Catija When some dish is described as belonging to a particular cuisine (e.g. *an Indian recipe*) the implication is that the dish originated in or is strongly associated with that cuisine. For example, chicken tikka masala is popular in many places, including the US, but it originated in India and is thus widely considered to be an Indian dish. The same cannot be said of oatmeal, with or without apples and cinnamon. It may be common in India, but I don't think most people would consider it to be strongly associated with that cuisine.

Comment: But that's not what you say in your answer. You say it's delicious and that it's ubiquitous in the US but you don't actually say that it's not associated with Indian cuisine. Do you see what I'm saying? If the question was "Is chicken tikka masala an Indian recipe?" and your answer was "It's a delicious chicken dish in all sorts of restaurants in the US" that doesn't say whether it's Indian or not. All it does is say that it exists in the US.

Comment: Yes, I guess when I wrote this answer nearly 5 years ago I didn't find it necessary to explain the meaning of *Indian recipe.* By pointing out that an identical concoction is very common breakfast food far from the subcontinent, I (think I) hoped to show that the dish is comfort food in many places and thus imply that it is not strongly connected to India. I could edit the answer to include the US origin of the machine that makes steel cut groats and how that lead to invention of the rolled oats called for in the recipe in question, but somehow I doubt that anyone cares.

Comment: Let's not get too confrontational here. Improving answers is always good, old or new. I edited in the missing bit Catija was pointing out; if you want to add a note about rolled oats actually being invented in the US that'd be most welcome as well, but I don't know exactly what you'd say.

Comment: Well done, @Jefromi.

Comment: The fact that the dish is associated with American cuisine doesn't indicate that it's not associated with Indian cuisine. Would you say that pizza can't be associated with American cuisine because it's associated with Italian cuisine? Or vice versa? It's often the case that a dish which originated in one culture becomes an integral part of a different culture, often undergoing significant changes.